# Vulnerability of secondary network if main network is hacked

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have set up a secondary WiFi network on my router for guests. I am hoping this gives me some modest level of protection from any consequences of their online shenanigans.

I'm wondering whether the protection runs both ways - whether they're (again, modestly) protected from any hacker managing to infiltrate the main network.

Comment: Unless the hacker sees another subnet and is skilled getting to that other subnet, then (modestly as you point out) the two subnets are protected from each other. I have two volunteer groups in the same building on the same main network and separated as discussed above. No issues after 3 years this way.

Comment: Thanks John. Just to be clear, it seems your groups are two separate sub-nets; I was wondering about the sub-net safety if the main network were somehow compromised.

Comment: If someone can get into your main router, see the subnets that exist, they may be able to traverse them. Your word "modestly" is the operative word. If they go to one subnet, they will not see the other unless they know about it.

Comment: Thanks very much, John. If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it. Assuming, of course, that I am allowed to as a newbie.

Comment: I did post as an answer and it is there for you to review

Comment: @John Great comments. Nice work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the hacker sees another subnet and is skilled getting to that other subnet, then (modestly as you point out) the two subnets are protected from each other. I have two volunteer groups in the same building on the same main network and separated as discussed above. No issues after 3 years this way.

f someone can get into your main router, see the subnets that exist, they may be able to traverse them. Your word "modestly" is the operative word. If they go to one subnet, they will not see the other unless they know about it.

I trust this helps you